# Add default user_id in migration as current_user variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I'm get error `StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: undefined local variable or method 'current_user'`.

when trying to make migrate this migration.

```
class AddDefaultUserId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :entity, :user_id, :integer, default: current_user 
  end
end
```

I need to find a way how to pass default `user_id` for `Entity` using `current_user`.

Answer (score 2):

`current_user` is a method that is generally defined in the context of a controller or a view, and it returns the authenticated user based on the request.

You are running a migration, which is a completely different context. You can't reference that method there because it is not defined.

Moreover, it doesn't make sense at all. The value you must provide as default in the database schema is a well defined "static" value, and it can't be the result of `current_user` as such value is expected to be calculated in real time based on the request.

Comment: Ok, my fault. But is there solution to get same result?

Comment: You could probably use before_create hook to set user_id field to some value, or always initialize entities referencing them from users' instance, e.g. user.entities.create(attributes_hash) if associations have been set up properly. I think there's no way to handle this in migration, only ruby-level hooks. And also some business logic details would be useful

Comment: @BogdanAgafonov how would look before_create hook for this problem?

Comment: @BogdanAgafonov You should model avoid callbacks, unless strictly necessary for data integrity. In this case, they are not. Callbacks may easily introduce side effects if used to track the life of other non-model-related objects or scopes.

Comment: @DanielsV I don't think that there's any possible usage of before_create hooks to tie entity to current_user, you could use it if there's some default user and user_id is not provided, and as Simone mentioned above, only if strictly necessary for data integrity. In your case, you probably should invoke entity creation on current_user, i.e. `current_user.entities.create entity_params`, but it depends on setting up the associations properly, with `has_many :entities` in User class and `belongs_to :user` in Entity class or similar, depending on your models and its relations.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti thanks for mentioning that, I was thinking wide because the problem seemed unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The migrations are a pathway to create the necessary columns in our database. we have created the migrations,then we do

```
rake db:migrate
```

then it will do the updations in database.The mechanism of

```
current_user
```

is only for finding the current user will provide the details of current user. Assume that any chance, your code works upon migration it only updates the details of user who does the migration. From your requirement; what i understood is you have to save the information on table about the current user. So there is no need to do that. so you have simply update the user_id of a user upon saving it. So by user_id we can get the information about the user.